# Selected map pins show the same coordinate

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview

I am trying get the coordinate of each pin I select on my map. Pins are the local search results that users search on the map. I have an issue that every pin I select it give me the same value. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)searchAction:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
    [self performSearch]; }

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *mypin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    //mypin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    mypin.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UIButton *goToDetail = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    mypin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = goToDetail;
    mypin.draggable = NO;
    mypin.highlighted = YES;
    mypin.animatesDrop = TRUE;
    mypin.canShowCallout = YES;
    return mypin;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = view.annotation;
    self.tappedCoord = annotation.coordinate;

    // Longs are the same for every pin I select
    NSLog(@"%f", [[view annotation] coordinate].longitude);
}

- (void)performSearch {
    MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _searchText.text;
    request.region = _mapView.region;

    self.matchingItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc]initWithRequest:request];

    [search startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
            NSLog(@"No Matches");
        else
            for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
            {
                [self.matchingItems addObject:item];
                MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
                annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate;
                annotation.title = item.name;
                annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@",
                                       item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"Street"],
                                       item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"State"],
                                       item.placemark.addressDictionary[@"ZIP"]];

                //NSLog(@"%@", item.placemark.addressDictionary);
                [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
            }
    }];
}
```

Comment: The code posted looks ok.  Are you sure it is the NSLog in calloutAccessoryControlTapped that is showing the same longitude for every pin?  Try logging the latitude and title as well.  In performSearch, log the coordinate and title of the annotation before adding to the map.  Are all the pins in a vertical line by any chance (resulting in the same longitude)?  Also log the latitude.

Comment: Thanks Anna. I just noticed that the longs and lats of those pins are different only in the 8th or 9th digit after the decimal (because they're too close to each other). Wish I should've noticed more carefully.